# How to replace a single class file inside signed jar?

Tags: java, jar, signed

I am new to Java. I have a basic question. I developed a Core Java application and deployed it as a signed jar (example App.jar). If I need to correct a single class file (assume that some major bug was found in the application) inside the jar what is the correct way to do ?

I do not want to release a new App.jar again. Is it possible to replace a single class file inside signed jar ?. Please guide me with your valuable suggestions.

Thanks
JK

Answer (score 4):

You have to build and sign a complete new jar. The whole purpose of signing is to avoid what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Could you please guide me on an approach/way to release an emergency patch/fix (here i don't want to do a complete build and release of new jar) of a java application that is deployed as signed jar ?

Comment: It is not possible. If you have this need, you shouldn't use signed jars.

Well perhaps - if you can place the .class file outside the jar; and before the jar in the classpath. But that's a bit of a shaky approach.